# Python stops working when using weight class in fitting of XGBoost

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, xgboost

I'm dealing with hight imbalanced data in a classification problem, so I use a weighted class in order to deal with this issue,
but Python stops working when I just run this Jupyter notebook cell (the fitting cell).

My code:

```
xg = XGBClassifier(objective ='reg:logistic', colsample_bytree = 0.3, learning_rate = 0.01,
            max_depth = 5, alpha = 10, n_estimators = 100)

class_weight = {0: 1,
            1: 9}

xg.fit(X_train,y_train,sample_weight=class_weight)
```

Comment: could you please post the number of training samples you have?

Comment: this is the shape of the sample : (1623, 83)

Comment: what does it mean python stops working? is it running but never finished or the kernel dies?

Comment: the kernel shut down

Comment: can you try to execute it by saving it as a py file ? than doing it in jupyter notebook for troubleshooting